# escape backticks - grave( ` ) when passing a argument to a ksh script in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ksh, gnu

I wrote a handy ksh shell script which reads the output a `firstcommand`, perform some filtering from grep, and resulting values are fed to `othercommand`

```
handy.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
othercommand `firstcommand | grep  'keyword' | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
```

It works very nicely.
However, I would like to pass my 'keyword'via command line. Normally I could use $1

```
>handy.ksh TEST
```

and inside the script $1 will be TEST
however, I can't escape the grave and $1 is interpreted literally.

How to escape ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$()` instead of backticks:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# test.ksh
echo $(echo "foo bar" | grep  "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Now you can call it like:

```
ksh test.ksh foo
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Anyhow, after posting my answer I realized that the same would work with backticks meaning I can't really reproduce your problem

Comment: mmm well thats another question :) but for now it works